# Java multithreading with wait and notify

Tags: java, multithreading, wait, notify

I have this piece of code

```
public MultiThreadedSum(ArrayBuffer ArrayBufferInst)
{
    this.ArrayBufferInst = ArrayBufferInst;
    Sum = 0;
    Flag = false;
    StopFlag = false;
}

public synchronized void Sum2Elements()
{

    while(Flag)
    {
        try {wait();}
        catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }

    Flag = true;

    if (StopFlag)
    {
        notifyAll();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Removing and adding 2 elements.");

    Sum = ArrayBufferInst.Sum2Elements();

    notifyAll();
}

public synchronized void InsertElement()
{

    while(!Flag)
    {
        try {wait();}
        catch (InterruptedException e){}
    }

    Flag = false;

    if (StopFlag)
    {
        notifyAll();
        return;
    }

    System.out.println("Inserting the sum.");

    ArrayBufferInst.InsertElement(Sum);

    if (ArrayBufferInst.RetunrSize() == 1)
    {
        StopFlag = true;
    }

    System.out.println(ArrayBufferInst);

    notifyAll();
}
```

As you can see, I set the Flag to be false first so one of the threads can enter the Sum2Elements method and change it to true and by that, making everyone wait.

I know that in synchronized code, only one thread can do its thing, well here I have two synchronized methods, does it mean that 2 threads are trying to conduct this methods after each notifyall?

And if so, is it not possible for one thread to enter Sum2Elements, change the flag to true before the other thread enters InsertElement, and by that skipping the while loop?

Thanks

Comment: @AmitD Do you mean `volatile`? `transient` simply indicates that a field should not be serialized in a class implementing Serializable.

Comment: Yes. I would like to correct myself use volatile as mentioned

Comment: @OP, please try to use the variable naming convention(name should start with small letter) , it confuses while reading your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Locks are obtained on objects of a class & not on any particular synchronized method.
Both the methods are instance methods. So if one of the threads have entered any synchronized method for an object, A say, then any other thread cant enter any synchronized method for that object until the running thread doesnt call `notifyAll()` method. At that stage all the waiting threads compete to become active but it depends on the thread scheduler to choose a thread which is to become active.

If you want that two different threads should access these synchronized methods simultaneously then the 2 threads should operate on 2 different objects of the class.

Answer (score 1):

Only one thread can hold the lock of the object. And then it's only that thread that can enter the synchronized methods on that object.

The thread can however release the lock without returning from the method, by calling Object.wait().

So your code looks good!

```
does it mean that 2 threads are trying to conduct this methods after each notifyall? 
Ans : It is very much possible for two threads to be in two of your synchronized methods since you are calling wait().

is it not possible for one thread to enter Sum2Elements, change the flag to true before the other thread enters InsertElement, and by that skipping the while loop?
Ans : Yes this is possible again for the same reason specified above.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "since you are calling wait()"? If I would not be using wait and have just 2 synchronized methods with two threads and execute them again with true and false, is it not possible for the two methods to be executed together? and as for the second answer, is there anything to do to avoid that? Thanks.

Comment: Unless you call wait 2 threads cannot execute two different sync methods of the same instance of a class. Reason being if one has lock on the instance of a class other thread cannot access any other sync method of same instance unless the 1st one calls wait() in which case thread1 release the lock but still stays in the 1st sync method.

Answer (score 0):

`Only one thread can execute one of two method at a time because both are synchronized  though order is undefined`

As I said one method can be executed by one thread at a time only unless executing thread release the `lock` by calling`wait` method and other thread get the `lock` and execute other `synchronized` method which make your both the statements **possible**.